# What webcam works with OpenCV/EmguCV

Tags: opencv, emgucv

Can anyone tell me which USB camera they have had success with when using the Capture functions of OpenCV/EmguCV 3.0? I have tried my Trust Webcam 1080p and Gearhead WC8500HD 1080p cameras and neither one works.

I know the capture capabilities of OpenCV/EmguCV work but it seems identifying the correct camera is not so easy. Maybe a 1080p HD camera is the problem? I have USB2 and USB3 so I don't think that's the problem. It cannot even connect to my integrated camera on my laptop!All the cameras work with AMCAP.

I am using Windows 7 x64 Professional, OpenCV/EmguCV 3.0 Visual Studio 13 C#

TIA,
Doug

Answer (score 1):

I have tried several Logitech webcams on OpenCV 2.X and Windows 7/XP. Do make sure that the camera drivers are installed first, and the camera can be used from other apps like Skype.

Comment: Thanks, Totoro. The cameras I have are plug & play and work with other programs without drivers. Is it possible that OpenCV/EnguCV require some kind of a driver?

Comment: Not sure about EmguCV, but OpenCV doesn't require drivers. The laptop camera should be fine, too.

Your can try this example (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture), and also try changing the zero in VideoCapture cap(0) to 1 or 2 (in case the default camera is pointing elsewhere).

Comment: This is a hard one, then. That code works fine on my side You should post this in the OpenCV Forums.

Comment: It is a bugger that's for sure! Which camera are you using to get this to work?

Comment: I have used Logitech HD WEBCAM C270, and many older models on Win XP, 7 and Ubuntu. On OS X, I always use the built-in webcam and that worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, Tontoro, I will give that camera a try!